# How to use state in data function in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Having problem to use state in data function of Vue. 
I tried this

```
this.items = this.$store.state.search_items
```

but it always results in an empty array like this

```
 [__ob__: Observer]
length: 0
__ob__: Observer {value: Array(0), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
__proto__: Array
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you !!

Here is the mutation from which I am stating search_items
this is working because I am able to see state.search_items in Vue dev tool

```
SET_WORKSPACES(state, payload) {
        state.workspaces = payload;
        var items = [];
        if (state.workspaces.length) {
            state.workspaces.forEach(function(workspace) {
                // Adding workspaces
                if (workspace.portfolios.length) {
                    items = [...items, ...workspace.portfolios];
                }
                // Adding projects
                if (workspace.projects.length) {
                    items = [...items, ...workspace.projects];
                    // Adding tasks
                    workspace.projects.forEach(function(project) {
                        if (project.tasks.length) {
                            items = [...items, ...project.tasks];
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        state.search_items = items;
    }
```

Data property

```
data() {
        return {
            results: [],
            keys: ['title','description'],
            list:this.items,
        }
    },
```

Comment: Sounds like `search_items` is an empty array.  We couldn't make a better guess without more information.

Comment: You need to post code related to mutations that update search_items

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: Next you'll need to show how/where you try to access it in the component, as well as any async calls.  It sounds as if you log the value before an async promise is resolved.

Comment: You are right so, in that case, what do I do. How to setInterval in the state ?

Answer (score 0):

If the state is updating correctly, the time taking for setting the state is making the issue. That means, the the function you're using to assign the `state` to `data` is rendering before the state set.

You can use a computed function that returning the state

```
computed:{
  items : function(){
    return this.$store.state.search_items;
  }
}
```

Now you can use the computed function name `items` same like a data variable.

Comment: This doesn't work data function always load before than state.So it always show empty result

Comment: You don't need to assign this to `data` since the computed function will work like `data`. Computed function is the best way to use `store` data in components.

Comment: But I need to use in data because the package which I am using needs the list from data function only.

Comment: Which package you're using? Can you please include that fraction of code where you using the data, in the question? Thank you.

Comment: The package name is Vue Fuse and I have updated the code.

Comment: Did you tried to use the computed function name in the package directly? You're trying to assign the `list:this.items`, what is the purpose of this line? Can you explain and please add how you're using the `list` in the package?

Comment: Computed property name is items so I have used `list:this.items`. Although I managed to get the result in data function by watch method. Thank you for the help.